# How to discover which technology a website is built upon?

Tags: vue.js, web, nuxt.js, content-management-system, velo

How can I know wether a website is based on Wordpress / Wix / React / Next.js / Nuxt.js / PHP etc?

I know answer for two, maybe you can help with other popular technologies.

1. Wordpress: I mostly check wether the https://theirdomain/wp-admin.php drop onto the login screen. It helps many times. And usually their html has prefixes based on their page builder. I.e. if they use `Elementor` is used, it has many `elementor-` prefix in the html tag names.
2. Next.js: Under `body` there is always a mandatory `<div>` with `id` `__next`.

I am most curious about the following two sites, what they could use:

- https://www.szauna-szeansz.hu
- https://sebeszem.hu

A software tools is welcome to propose to get infos about used technologies in websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wappalyzer: https://www.wappalyzer.com/

Or tech specific devtools like the VueJS ones or Vue telescope, then React ones etc...

Otherwise, checking the source code.

---

For the first one

[image]

For the second one

[image]

Then it comes down to know a bit of e-commerce platforms etc.

Comment: Yoomla I know, but what is the core technology for second, do you know? Is it a CMS  a custom site?

Comment: @János looks like nothing specific. At least I couldn't see any specific framework used for that one. There is a lot of custom JS/jQuery too so I don't think it's that popular/great anyway. Why are you asking? Want to achieve something similar?